# How to add view to a PRISM TabControl region WITHOUT making it selected?

Tags: .net, wpf, c#-4.0, prism-5

We have a WPF application using PRISM, with a region of type TabControl.

```
    <TabControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.ContentRegion}">
        <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding TabName}" />
            </Style>
        </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </TabControl>
```

And we are registering views with

```
_regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.ContentRegion, typeof(ContentView));
```

Problem is, this way the registered tab automatically gets selected. Is there a way to add a view as tab but NOT select it??

Comment: Have you tried activating the previously active view after registration?

Comment: Well, no, I did not mention it in my post but I wanted to prevent the UserControl.Loaded event to fire because some heavy work was done there. Eventually I fixed that as well, but only as a part of a bigger solution which was to implement custom RegionAdapter for tab control, which gives me more control.

Answer (score 4):

The solution I came up with is to implement an interface for each view, and implement a custom RegionAdapter which uses it.

**Note:** This interface also allows you to specify tab order, if you need it as well.

```
public interface ITabItemView
{
    int TabItemIndex { get; }

    bool IsStartupTab { get; }
}

public class TabControlRegionAdapter : RegionAdapterBase<TabControl>
{
    private ITabItemView startupTab = null;

    public TabControlRegionAdapter(IRegionBehaviorFactory factory)
        : base(factory)
    {

    }

    protected override void Adapt(IRegion region, TabControl regionTarget)
    {
        region.Views.CollectionChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
                {
                    var items = regionTarget.Items;

                    foreach (ITabItemView tab in e.NewItems)
                    {
                        if (tab.TabItemIndex > items.Count)
                            items.Add(tab);
                        else
                            items.Insert(tab.TabItemIndex, tab);

                        if (tab.IsStartupTab)
                        {
                            if (tab != startupTab && startupTab != null)
                                throw new InvalidOperationException("More than one tab is the startup tab.");

                            startupTab = tab;

                            regionTarget.SelectedItem = tab;
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
    }

    protected override IRegion CreateRegion()
    {
        return new AllActiveRegion();
    }
}
```

And of course in your Bootstrapper class you need

```
protected override Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.RegionAdapterMappings ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings()
    {
        var mappings = base.ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings();
        mappings.RegisterMapping(typeof(TabControl), Container.Resolve<TabControlRegionAdapter>());
        return mappings;
    }
```