# Can I put region in TabItem control?

Tags: wpf, prism

I have the following code to display views.

```
<TabControl>
     <TabItem x:name=View1 ...>
           <TabItem.Header>
               <Grid>
                  <local:View1 />
               </Grid>
           </TabItem.Header>
     </TabItem>
     <TabItem x:name=View2 ...>
            <TabItem.Header>
               <Grid>
                  <local:View2 />
               </Grid>
           </TabItem.Header>
     </TabItem>
     <TabItem x:name=View3 ...>
         <TabItem.Header>
               <Grid>
                  <local:View3 />
               </Grid>
           </TabItem.Header>
     </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Now for some navigation purpose I want to navigate to the view from different module. So I guess that I have to add the regions to the views.

So can I add the regions to the TabItem controls? Such as

```
<TabControl>
     <TabItem x:name=View1 prism:RegionManager.RegionName="Region1".../>
     <TabItem x:name=View2 prism:RegionManager.RegionName="Region2".../>
     <TabItem x:name=View3 prism:RegionManager.RegionName="Region3".../>
</TabControl>
```

Or I have to replace `TabItem` with `ContentControl`? The question is that somehow the code is in the production. If I change it not sure any negative effects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place a `ContentControl` within each `TabItem` and host the regions there.

The "normal" `TabControlRegionAdapter` you find by googling (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30071300/how-to-add-view-to-a-prism-tabcontrol-region-without-making-it-selected)) lets you host the region in the `TabControl` so that a `TabItem` is created for each view you add to the region - that does *not* seem to be what you want here.

```
<TabControl>
     <TabItem x:name=View1>
         <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="Region1"/>
     </TabItem>
     <TabItem x:name=View2>
         <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="Region2"/>
     </TabItem>
     <TabItem x:name=View3>
         <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="Region3"/>
     </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: You can put a `ContentControl` in the header, too, and host `HeaderRegion1` (and 2, 3...) there.